# Clickale label for dropdown select option group

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to have the label sel? ie the Swedish Cars?

I am trying to achieve an indent select menu for a search. Where swedish cars are the category. Currently you cannot select Swedish cars as it is a label. But i need to be able to search the full category Swedish Cars.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Im think you have to do pseudo select

Comment: Or maybe make <optgroup> as <option class="optgroup"> and check it when click. But this bad idea for design.

Comment: So you want swedish cars to be a value and a label? It's not clear what you want the result to be

Comment: Yes thats correct. Currently option tags are indented which is perfect. I can only achieve this by adding the label which is not indented